# На телефоне с Android 8.1 кнопки "Назад" и "домой" работают неправильно

Tags: android

В своей программе онлайн-радио делаю обработчик кнопки "Назад", в котором закрываю программу:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
    }
```

Кнопку "домой" не обрабатываю, но есть обработчики `onStop()`, в котором я запускаю сервис уведомления в "шторке", и `onRestart()`, в котором я прекращаю сервис уведомления. Все работает у меня на стареньком телейфоне с API 16, работает и на эмуляторах с API 19 и 25. Но вот на телефоне заказчика One Plus c Android 8.1 при нажатии на кнопку назад программа не останавливается, а при нажатии на кнопку "action" запускается еще один экземпляр программы, и звуки программ накладываются друг на друга. В манифесте программы я указала `android:launchMode="singleTask"` Эмулятора arm Oreo нет в природе(на сколько я знаю), аппаратного ускорения у меня нет, чтобы скачать без arm, и взять у заказчика телефон, чтобы протестировать я тоже не могу. Где копать, подскажите!

Comment: Что за кнопка "action"?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос писала со слов заказчика. Нашла эмулятор 8.0 - кнопка назад работает как надо, а кнопка "домой" (заказчик ее "action" назвал) работала неправильно по моей вине - по нажатию на кнопку должен запуститься сервис уведомления, а на Орео изменился синтаксис запуска уведомлений. После исправления этого пункта и добавления в программу отслеживание аудиофокуса, никаких проблем с программой ни на 8.1, ни на 4.2 не наблюдается. Вопрос сам собой отпал.